# How to insert constant values in SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a constant value in SQL. Here's a little snippet from a program I'm building in Java to illustrate what I mean.

```
PreparedStatement customerInsert = 
DBconnection.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer 
(customerId, customerName, addressId, active, createDate, createdBy, 
lastUpdate, lastUpdateBy) + "VALUES( null, null, null, null, 
UTC_TIMESTAMP(), \"" + LogInController.getUserName() + "\", UTC_TIMESTAMP(), 
\"" + LogInController.getUserName() + "\");");
```

The null values are just place holders, the value I'm trying to keep constant is the active value. This SQL is inserting values from text fields from the user, there's no textfield for active. I'd just like it to always be 1 when a user submits a form. Does anyone know what I need to put as the value in this insert statement to make sure that value for active is always 1? I'm getting an error in MySQL Workbench when I test out the insert statement when I just put 1 as the value. I've checked other StackOverflow answers to try to figure it out. I've also looked through some documentation and watched an SQL course on Lynda.com. I haven't had any luck figuring it out. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error when you tried to put 1 as the value for active column?

Comment: Why don't you make 'active' value equals to 1 on db side, you can set a condition to column to set always fix value 1, there is default value condition for every column type...

Comment: Do as Hayra suggests

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. After seeing all the suggestions and critiques of my implementation I'm going to refactor my whole approach. Thank you all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
final int ACTIVE = 1;
```

and pass it to your sql statement

or you can make the default value 1 for it in your DB implemenation

Comment: Oh man, I feel silly for not thinking of making it a variable and making it final. Thank you!